Celery-Backend setup
I am using Celery with RabbitMQ to utilize the queuing feature, and I am mixing it with Flask.
Following the documentation step by step, one of the options that I am trying to use is the backend option when preparing celery app. I'm setting it up to use Redis, but when I try to use job.get(), I get this exception:

raise NotImplementedError(E_NO_BACKEND.strip())
NotImplementedError: No result backend is configured.

Here is the setup of the Celery app:
celery = Celery('CeleryConfig',
                broker='amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672',
                backend='redis://localhost:6379',
                include=['tasks'],
                worker_prefetch_multiplier=1,
                result_persistent=True,
                result_serializer='json',
                task_serializer='json',
                accept_content=['json'])

